# You are dealt a hand of 5 cards from a normal deck of cards. In how many ways could you be dealt at least 4 hearts?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, card-games

You are dealt a hand of 5 cards from a normal deck of cards. In how many ways could you be dealt at least 4 hearts?

I was working on this problem as part of a multiple choice quiz and was stumped by the available options. I thought this was a simple problem involving just choosing 4 hearts of the 13 hearts available and then multiplying that by the 48 remaining cards, yielding 34320, but the answer key claims it's in fact 29172. What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Your method overcounts heart flushes.  Specifically, you count each heart flush $5$ times (once for each card in the hand).

Comment: On review:  I have no idea where your number came from.  $\binom {13}4\times 48=34320$ which is not what you wrote.

Comment: Oh, apparently you multiplied $\binom {13}4$ by $52$, but that doesn't make sense .

Comment: @lulu apologies. I got mixed up with my answer and one of the answer keys. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: No worries.  Do you understand the overcounting?

Comment: I don't fully comprehend it quite yet, but giving it some thought.

Comment: If it is difficult to see why your answer is incorrect, consider the much smaller problem of where the deck contained only five cards in it, those five cards being the $A,2,3,4$ and $5$ of hearts.  There is only one way to take a hand of five cards (*order irrelevant*) from this deck which had only five cards to begin with.  According to your calculations however you would have had counted $5$ possibilities, one for each of the ways of picking the "last" card.

Comment: For a corrected approach, consider counting the number of hands with *exactly* four hearts and one non-heart and adding to that the number of hands with *exactly* five hearts, emphasizing the fact that here for the five-heart hand we can't distinguish which of the five cards might have been the "last" card picked.

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough responses and helping me to understand my fault here! I'm seeing now why I was making this mistake. Still thinking through this a bit more, but really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Ahhhh, I think I get it now. Silly me... Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Let's represent as follows.

$H$- Obtaining a heart card

$O$-Obtaining other card

Obtaining at leat 4 hearts=$(HHHHO)+(HHHHH)$

$P$(obtaining at least 4 hearts)=$P(HHHHO)+P(HHHHH)$

The Number of ways to select 5 cards= $\binom{52}{5}$

The Number of ways to select 4 hearts and one other card = $\binom{13}{4}\cdot\binom{39}{1}$

The number of ways to select 5 hearts= $\binom{13}{5}$

$$P(HHHHO)=\frac{\binom{13}{4}\cdot\binom{39}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}=\frac{27885}{2598960}$$

$$P(HHHHH)=\binom{13}{5}/\binom{52}{5}=1287/2598960$$

$P$(obtaining at least 4 hearts)=$27885/2598960+1287/2598960$

$P$(obtaining at least 4 hearts)=$11/980$   (Final answer)